# Select rows that are less than 5 minutes old using DATE_SUB

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a table that is getting hundreds of requests per minute.  The issue that I'm having is that I need a way to select only the rows that have been inserted in the past 5 minutes. I am trying this:

```
SELECT count(id) as count, field1, field2
FROM table
WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

My issue is that it returns 70k+ results and counting.  I am not sure what it is that I am doing wrong, but I would love to get some help on this.  In addition, if there were a way to group them by minute to have it look like:

```
| count | field1 | field2 | 
----------------------------
```

I'd love the help and direction on this, so please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: What is the type of `timestamp` column?

Comment: @tadeck it's a datetime, would that make a difference?

Comment: It makes huge difference, as some people use `INT` for storing timestamps. Also it differs from `TIMESTAMP` type, because `DATETIME` is treated literally and does not adjust for the timezone. This may be the problem - compare the timestamp of recently inserted entry with the result of `SELECT NOW();` and let us know about the values of both.

Comment: Just remember to do that query on exact same database you queried in your question. It has some timezone settings that will influence the results.

Comment: @tadek that certainly made a big difference.  I am almost certain that this is working now. The only reason I'm questioning is because my original datetimes were an hour or so ahead of this machine's time, so it hasn't surpassed the old datetimes yet.  I will let you know shortly

Comment: Generally this is a good idea to use the same scheme, eg. 1) store Unix epoch integers in the database, or 2) convert Unix epoch integers to the `TIMESTAMP` columns and back on the database layer, or 3) convert Unix epoch integers to `DATETIME` strings and back on the application's layer. Otherwise there is a place for timezone mismatch.

Answer (score 24):

You don't really need `DATE_ADD/DATE_SUB`, date arithmetic is much simpler:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
FROM `table`
WHERE `timestamp` >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 4):

The following seems like it would work which is mighty close to what you had:

```
SELECT 
  MINUTE(date_field) as `minute`,
  count(id) as count
FROM table 
WHERE date_field > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)
GROUP BY MINUTE(date_field)
ORDER BY MINUTE(date_field);
```

Note the added column to show the minute and the GROUP BY clause that gathers up the results into the corresponding minute.  Imagine that you had 5 little buckets labeled with the last 5 minutes.  Now imagine you tossed each row that was 4 minutes old into it's own bucket.  count() will then count the number of entries found in each bucket.  That's a quick visualization on how GROUP BY works.  http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php seems to be a decent writeup on GROUP BY if you need more info.

If you run that and the number of entries in each minute seems too high, you'll want to do some troubleshooting.  Try replacing COUNT(id) with MAX(date_field) and MIN(date_field) so you can get an idea what kind of dates it is capturing.  If MIN() and MAX() are inside the range, you may have more data written to your database than you realize.

You might also double check that you don't have dates in the future as they would all be > now().  The MIN()/MAX() checks mentioned above should identify that too if it's a problem.